# R: How to specify x-axis value using categorical variable or trace value in a plot

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have a dataset like the following:

```
      derv         Season   Date
  1 -32.497029042   2008sp  2008-01-02
  2 -32.309188148   2008sp  2008-01-03
  ......
  3 -32.121614690   2008au  2008-07-04
  4 -31.934310377   2008au  2008-07-07
  ......
  5 -31.747276914   2009sp  2009-01-08 
  6 -31.560516012   2009sp  2009-01-09
  ......
  7 -31.374029378   2009au  2009-07-10
  8 -31.187818719   2009au  2009-07-11
  ......
  9 -31.001885744   2014sp  2014-01-14
  10 -30.816232161  2014sp  2014-01-15
```

I used the following code to create a plot:

```
  plot(d1, type = "l",main = "derivative",  xlim = c(0,1800))
  abline(h = 0)
  abline(h = 2.578269274, col = "red")
  abline(h = -1.4242559021, col = "purple")
```

[image]

And I want to know at which date or which season, d1 (derivative) crosses the three horizontal lines. But the x-axis value does not really allow to trace the date or season when d1 (derivative) crosses those horizontal lines.
So, I am wondering if there is a way that I can put the Season as in the x-axis or if there is a way that I can trace values on the plot.

New to R, would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Try to plot by "axes = FALSE" parameter first, and then use "axis" to draw the x/y axis with the label you want separately.

Comment: I tried but it did not work well. It is still hard for me to see tell the date

Comment: Are you specifically asking how to make a graph, or do you want to know how to simply extract the value of interest?

Comment: I am more interested in plotting the graph